# Jenkins Email notification for multiple builds

Tags: jenkins

I need suggestion for Jenkins project (multi-conf or pipeline) and plugins that will fit my work.

I have 10 "flavors" of the product, so I must build 10 times every time I commit to the repository (all in the same workspace).
Today I have 10 jobs (freestyle) and a "master" job that trigger the rest.
I tried to add Email notification (using Email Extension Plugin) but I want only one Email report for all the builds, not 10 Emails.

I understand that I should change to one multi-configuration project or one pipeline project that will handle all the builds, so it will be easier to trigger only one Email, but what is the best practice to get only one Email report on multiple builds?

Comment: Do the jobs run in parallel or sequentially?

Comment: In sequentially and should keep it that way, because all the jobs compile on the same workspace.

Answer (score 1):

The other option you could try is to add email notification as part of your build script. I use ANT build script and call the email notification target from my jenkins job instead of using the email plugin

Answer (score 1):

If you had one e-mail job that was a downstream of all the other jobs finishing via the [Join Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Join+Plugin), the e-mail job should only fire off after everything is completed.

It seems the "normal" build trigger will cause an issue. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25912639/how-to-build-a-jenkins-project-only-when-two-other-projects-have-successfully-be